# It is not a function

Tags: javascript, json

I just do this simple thing:

```
$(function () {
    $("div").on("hover", function (event) {
        if (event.type === "mouseenter") {
            $(this).css("background", "blue");
        } 
        else {
            $(this).css("background", "red");
        }
    });
});
```

But it says by this line:

```
$("div").on("hover", function (event) {
```

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

Thank you

but if I do this:

```
    $(function () {
        $("div").on("click", function (event) {
            alert("Your mouse is at X " + event.pageX + " and at Y " + event.pageY);
        });
    });
```

I get the same error

Thank you ALl!! it was a css issus.

Comment: You have jquery included?

Comment: yes, ofcourse, it is a standard asp.net mvc application. I am using 1.8.2.js

Comment: It seams that $("div") returns undefined or null which both have no on() method. Try `console.log($("div"));`

Comment: Did your put `<script>` tag with your script below `<script>` tag with jQuery?

Comment: Can you also add your HTML code? You try to access `$("div")` which may results in multiple divs in your document.

Comment: `$(function() { ...})` is ok, so yes, jq is turn on. Problem in `$('div')`.

Comment: yes, <script></script>

Comment: Look at the actual HTML via the browser "view source" tool to make sure that jQuery is being imported and that the JavaScript code in your question appears **after** the import of jQuery.

Comment: Try `alert([typeof $.fn.bind, typeof $.fn.on])` to check if you have an older version of jQuery that doesn't have `on` function.

Comment: so if you open the console and type `$` does it throw any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function` appears when you have not included jQuery.

If you are loading jQuery locally, check the path.

You can also load jQuery via CDNs like Google Hosted Libraries https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/

Answer (score 0):

Check that your put `<script>` tag with your script below `<script>` tag with jQuery

Answer (score -4):

Use

```
$(".selector").on("mouseover", function () {
    //stuff to do on mouseover
});
```

or

```
$(".selector").hover(function () {
    //stuff to do on mouseover
});
```